# textbox max characters without special characters

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a text box with numeric values and thousand separators etc. For ex: 12,111,111,111.804

The max length is 14 characters.

The problem is that when I edit that text box it counts the special characters and not allowing to enter the new value to the box. how do I simply eliminate the special characters form the max length.

Edit:

Sorry guys was out of the town . Lets say we take the following no : 12,312,312,312,312 . so there are 14 digits. and i erase last 3. so it will be 12,312,312,312, . now i want to add another 3 digits for the once i deleted. I'm using .net 2.0. this is a windows application.

Comment: @user1737909 yeah, that's the best solution

Comment: @Sri: Why not simply increase the max length?

Comment: @Otiel - yes, to assist the ASP.NET controls.

Comment: @sri - what special characters? Please give examples. Also indicate which GUI framework.

Comment: See my answer below. It does exactly what is required but for some reason i got a down vote.

Comment: @CathalMF - Please find my comment for your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a keyPress event and include the below code. 
Replace >= 5 with the max size of your text box not including the decimals or commas.

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
        if(textBox1.Text.Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "").Length >= 5)
            e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution. but there is a problem. Lets say we take the following no : 12,312,312,312,312 . so there are 14 digits. and i erase last 3. so it will be 12,312,312,312, . now i want to add another 3 digits for the once i deleted. But it does not enable to type.

Comment: I think I have set the maxLength property to 14. i removed it and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use following jquery code by customizing it as your need:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#textbox1').keyup(function (event)
    {
        var currentValue = $(this).val();
        var length = currentValue.length;
        var commaCount = 0;

        // Get Comma Count
        for (i = 0; i < this.value.length; i++)
        {
            if (this.value.charAt(i) == ',')
                commaCount++;
        }

        if (length > 3)
        {
            // remove comma's to work out the number of digits.
            length = length - commaCount;
        }

        if (length<=14)
        {
            $(this).val(currentValue);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("validation fails! length can not exceed 14 digits");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: User specified c# in tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Linq` to count the digits in the string

```
int count = textBox1.Text.Count(char.IsNumber);
```

So you could use like

```
if (textBox1.Text.Count(char.IsNumber) <= 14)
{
    //valid
}
```